# PostSharp - System.InvalidOperationException when applying to mscorlib -> System.DateTime

Tags: date, datetime, postsharp, invalidoperationexception

i tried setting the multicastattributes to public to exclude internal and private methods but still no luck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: test.AOP(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib",
    AttributeTargetTypes = "System.DateTime")]

namespace test
{
    [Serializable]
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
    class AOP : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entry: " + args.Method.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

To test this just call anywhere on your code something like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

i think the Date part is causing the problem. The solution could be to exclude that but this could happen in the future with other methods so i need a more "sure" solution

Comment: This seems like a bug in the weaved code. Thanks for reporting it. We will let you know as soon as it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed since PostSharp 4.3.30 and PostSharp 5.0.21.